# Combining all of the tables for multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have five tables namely `countryCities`, `countryProvinces`, `countryRegions`, `countryStatus`, `countryRestrictions`

I need to combine all of the tables given the columns of each. This is currently what I came up with:

```
select cc.id, cc.name, cc.is_city, cp .id, cp.name, cp.key, cr.id, cr.name, cr.long_name, cr .key,
cs.id, cs.id, cs.status, cr.start, cr.end, cr.travelAllowed
from countryCities as cc
inner join countryProvinces cp ON cc.id=cp.id
inner join countryRegions cr ON cp.id=cr.id
inner join countryStatus cs ON cp.id=cr.id
inner join countryRestrictions cr ON cp.id=cr.id
```

I'm not sure if I really did combine since my rows have been reduced into around a hundred. There are supposed to be a total of 1k rows for each table. Only `countryStatus` has 5 rows. The rest has 1k rows

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

First, replace your inner join with left join. Your current sql query doesn't return cities that don't have either:  a province, a region, a status or restrictions. [Here's an explanation of JOINS.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Second, do all your provinces have cities? Do all your regions have provinces? If the answer is No/I'm not sure then you need to do a UNION with queries that starts from province and from region, with either null or a default value for fields related to cities. Here's an example for province :

```
select NULL, NULL, NULL, cp .id, cp.name, cp.key, cr.id, 
cr.name, cr.long_name, cr .key,
cs.id, cs.id, cs.status, cr.start, cr.end, cr.travelAllowed
from countryProvinces as cp
inner join countryRegions cr ON cp.id=cr.id
inner join countryStatus cs ON cp.id=cs.id
inner join countryRestrictions cre ON cp.id=cre.id
```

Comment: my countryStatus  only has 5 rows. My problem is that when I do inner join, I only get 5 rows. For left join, I would get 1k+ rows but a lot of null values. Is there a way wherein I can combine all tables despite one table having a different number of rows?

Comment: There's a problem with your ids then. I saw it in your request but i thought it was for demonstration purpose. You need to rename the id column of the countryStatus since in your query you're trying to join the id of the Province with the id of the Status. Since you only have 5 status, your query will only return 5 row.